# How do I create a bar chart where y axis measures mean of a variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, mean

[image: barplot I want to recreate]

The y-axis I have is a variable of type 'double'.
The x-axis is of type factor (changed it from character).

I made this plot years ago and have no idea how to do it in either the base or ggplot2 package. I want to get the mean of the y axis variable.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ggplot` you can use the option `stat="summary"` and `fun="mean"` to automatically get the averages on your y-axis. Here an example without average values and with average values:

```r
df <- data.frame(result = c("Lost", "Win", "Lost", "Win"),
                 shoot_time = c(8, 6, 9, 7))  

library(ggplot2)
# Just y value on barplot
ggplot(df, aes(x = result, y = shoot_time)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "Game Result", y = "Total Time to Shoot")
```

[image]

```r
# Averages on y-axis
ggplot(df, aes(x = result, y = shoot_time)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean") +
  labs(x = "Game Result", y = "Average Time to Shoot")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. First in base R and second in `ggplot2`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

shoot_data <- data.frame("result" = c("Winner", "Loser"),
                         "avrgtime" = c(8.48, 9.53))

# Plot with base R
barplot(shoot_data$avrgtime ~ shoot_data$result,
        ylab = "Average Time to Shoot",
        xlab = "Game Result",
        ylim = c(0,10))
```

[image]

```r
# Plot with GGplot2
shoot_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = result, y = avrgtime))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  ylab("Average Time to Shoot")+
  xlab("Game Result")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>